# Left outer join with condition sql

Tags: sql, db2

would anybody know if there is way to do conditional left outer join? I have ledger tables with actuals and reference department table from which I want to assign BMDIV.
But department reference table contains LC number or = 'xx'
What I want to do is to join ledger table with department table on LCTRYNUM, LC and DEPTNUM but in the case of LC = '**' join would be only LCTRYNUM and DEPTNUM.

**Ledger acutal table**

| LCTRYNUM | LC | DEPTNUM | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 618 | 40 | 30813 | 100 |
| 618 | 50 | 30813 | 200 |
| 618 | 60 | 30813 | 300 |
| 618 | 10 | 30813 | 100 |

**Business Division reference table**

| LCTRYNUM | LC | DEPTNUM | BMDIV |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 618 | ** | 30813 | 30 |
| 618 | 10 | 30813 | 2P |

**Expected result would be this**

| LCTRYNUM | LC | DEPTNUM | Amount | BMDIV |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 618 | 40 | 30813 | 100 | 30 |
| 618 | 50 | 30813 | 200 | 30 |
| 618 | 60 | 30813 | 300 | 30 |
| 618 | 10 | 30813 | 100 | 2P |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two `left join`s, the first to bring in direct matches and the second for the default match:

```
select a.*, coalesce(d.bmdiv, d_default.bmdiv) as bmdiv
from actual a left join
     divisions d
     on a.lc = d.lc left join
     divisions d_default
     on d_default.lc = '**'
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon. This solution was exactly what I was looking for.